# Настройка политики API

Tags: php, api, token

Если человек хочет воспользоваться нашим `API`, он делает следующее:

1. Получает токен
2. С токеном обращается к `API`

Естественно, токены будут уникальными.

Собственно, вопрос: Как защитить этот токен? Чтобы он был доступен только для одного человека. То есть чтобы нельзя было взять этот токен у другого человека и поставить себе. К чему нужно привязывать?

1. `IP` - не подходит, так как он может быть динамическим.
2. `Referer`- тоже не подходит, так как можно подменить

Также должна быть "кроссплатформенность" токена, то есть чтобы взять его, и, например, перенести в Андроид приложение и там пользоваться `API`

P.S. Нужно без регистрации пользователя (!)

Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)/[OAuth](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)?

Т.е. идея в том, чтобы идентифицировать пользователя через сторонний ресурс, например соц. сети.

Answer (score 0):

Тут приходит на ум только генерация ключа на стороне клиента, только я не знаю какая у вас задача и что можно требовать от клиента. Можно ли требовать для получения ключа запустить ваш скрипт у себя на машине? Если можно, то там уже проще. Пару ключей генерите и все. Как банки делают.

Comment: "запустить ваш скрипт у себя на машине?" - не совсем понял вас. Что  это мне даст?

Comment: Ну типа пару ключей генерите. Хотя конечно, если пользователь сам будет заинтересован в передаче токена, то он и приватный ключ свой передаст